# PagedListView shows CircularProgressIndicator in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I used `infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0` to implement pagination in the flutter web.
I got response from API but in UI it still shows CircularProgressIndicator. I am using GetX .
UI part is,

```
PagedListView<int, dynamic>(
                                  pagingController:
                                  collectionController.pagingControllerLibraryDetails,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  builderDelegate:
                                  PagedChildBuilderDelegate<dynamic>(
                                      itemBuilder: (context, item, indexs) {
                                        return Obx(
                                                () {
                                              return
                                              Text(collectionController.libraryAllContentResponse2.value.data!.rows![indexs].categoryName.toString());
                                            }
                                        );
                                      },
                                      noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (_) =>
                                          CollectionEmptyScreen()))
```

Api call in Getxcontroller,
final PagingController<int, dynamic> pagingControllerLibraryDetails=
PagingController(firstPageKey: 1);

```
getLibInsideContent(
        pages
        ) async {
      try {
        SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        libraryAllContentRequest. page= pages;
        libraryAllContentRequest.pageSize = 10;
        libraryAllContentRequest.loggedInUserID = pref.getString("userId");
        qry.libraryId = libraryId.value;
        libraryAllContentRequest.query = Query(libraryId:libraryId.value
        );
        try {
          var res = await libraryProvider
              .getAllLibContent(libraryAllContentRequest.toJson());

     

 if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          LibraryAllContentResponse libraryAllContentResponse =
          LibraryAllContentResponse.fromJson(res.body);
          if (libraryAllContentResponse2.value.data != null) {
            final isLastPage = int.parse(libraryAllContentResponse.data!.rows!.length.toString())< 10;
            if(isLastPage){
              pagingControllerLibraryDetails.appendLastPage(
                libraryAllContentResponse.data!.rows!,
              );
            }
            else{
              final nextPageKey = pages +1;
              pagingControllerLibraryDetails.appendPage( libraryAllContentResponse.data!.rows!, nextPageKey);
            }
            libraryAllContentResponse.data!.rows!.forEach((element) {
              if (!libraryAllContentResponse2.value.data!.rows!.contains(element)) {
                libraryAllContentResponse2.value.data!.rows!.add(element);
              }
            });
          } else {
            libraryAllContentResponse2.value = libraryAllContentResponse;
          }

          return libraryAllContentResponse;
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          // print(e);
          return e;
        }
      }

      Get.snackbar('Loding', 'Issue');
      return null;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
   
      return "e";
    }
  } on Exception catch (e) {
 
  }
}
```

I called  getLibInsideContent(pages) functions in the success response of another api calls.(`getLibInsideContent(1);`)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
Added listener in initstate();

```
 @override
    void onInit() {
      pagingControllerLibraryDetails.addPageRequestListener((page) => getLibInsideContent(page));
 super.onInit();
     
    }
```